# Azure AD login without https

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory

Using this tutorial I am able to setup AzureAD authentication on my application:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-asp-webapp

But I would like to be able to run it locally without using https. Is that possible?

If i change my redirecturi to http://localhost/mytestapp/ in my code and the azure application, I get an error: IDX21323: RequireNonce is 'System.Boolean'...

Comment: You need to change the redirecturi to `http://localhost/mytestapp/` both in the `code` and in the `Azure portal`.

Comment: @CarlZhao Updated post to reflect that i update redirecturi in both code and azure application.

Comment: I've been where you are right now. You're WAAAYY better off just running localhost with https. You can do so by running it between port 44300 and 44399.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue in Chromium browsers. Chrome won't save the cookie when using `SameSite=None` if the traffic is over HTTP.You can disable the flag at `chrome://flags/#same-site-by-default-cookies` to make it work with chrome.

For more details refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/samesite/owin-samesite).

Comment: I believe a similar setting for firefox is network.cookie.sameSite.laxByDefault